# Order multiarray based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays like

```
$originalArray = [
    ...
    [
    ...
    'attribute' => 'value'
    ....
    ],
    [
    ...
    'attribute' => 'year'
    ....
    ],
    [
    ...
    'attribute' => 'car'
    ....
    ],
    ....
];
```

and I have another array which defines the desired order of the previous array.

```
$desiredOrderArray = ['car', 'value', 'year'];
```

My desired output would be

```
$newArrayOrdered = [
    [
    ...
    'attribute' => 'car'
    ....
    ],
    [
    ...
    'attribute' => 'value'
    ....
    ],
    [
    ...
    'attribute' => 'year'
    ....
    ],
];
```

I'm doing this "reorder" process iteracting over the arrays and creating a new array in the desired order. Is there a better way to do it? Some function or whatever

Comment: Messy but you could split that array into 3 arrays using a foreach, then merge the arrays at the end in the order you want it to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the order array as-is is not optimal as it necessitates multiple array searches for any approach you use.

If you flip it so that its values become keys, you can look up the order using attribute as a key when you use it in a `usort` comparison function.

```
$order = ['car', 'value', 'year'];

$order = array_flip($order);  // ['car' => 0, 'value' => 1, 'year' => 2]

usort($originalArray, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    return $order[$a['attribute']] <=> $order[$b['attribute']];
});
```

With `usort`, this won't create a new array; it will sort the original array.

Comment: This works but i'm not sure of the cost if I have bigger arrays. I'll make some tests on that. Thank you

Comment: Just made some tests. Usually this runs 4 times faster than iterating over the arrays like I was doing. I my case it does not make a big difference because usually i don't have more than 30 items but it's good to know anyway.

Comment: That makes sense. Converting the order array to attribute => order format is probably the thing that makes the most difference. That reduces the complexity in the comparison function to a simple comparison between two hash table lookups. At that point it's just quicksort, so it's the about same complexity as using `sort` on a simliar size array of ints.